# Blog link is relative when it should be absolute

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, footer

The blog link at the bottom of meta.stackoverflow is relative.

E.g. the one at the bottom of this question links to ...meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250147/blog.stackexchange.com?blb=1

[Related meta report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229745/blog-link-is-relative-while-it-should-be-absolute).

Comment: @m0sa Now I also note these blog links in the SO footer go to blog.SE, but there is a blog.SO, and the blog link on the RHS in the Community Bulletin does link to it, so I guess the footer should too.